# Attempting to toggle between 2 classes of CSS/HTML for a neat animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Feel free to use this source if you'd like to visualize my issue for yourself, I feel as though I'm overcomplicating it a bit.

I know that I could go the route of individually transitioning the elements using an ID but I'm trying to understand a little more JavaScript and feel like this might be the easiest and most space efficient way to manage my code when wanting to transition several elements at once.

```js
function bubblefade() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("bubbles");
  if (element.getElementsByClassName = "bubbles") {
    element[0].classList.replace("bubbles", "bubblefadestyle")
    element[0].classList.replace("bubbles", "bubblefadestyle")
    element[0].classList.replace("bubbles", "bubblefadestyle")
  } else {
    element[0].classList.replace("bubblefadestyle", "bubbles")
    element[0].classList.replace("bubblefadestyle", "bubbles")
    element[0].classList.replace("bubblefadestyle", "bubbles")
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

#logo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#logo:active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.05s;
}

.bubblefadestyle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bubbles {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bubbles:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.bubbles:active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.05s;
}

#bubble1 {
  padding-top: 130%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
`
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
  <html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div onclick="bubblefade();" id="logo">
      <img src="assests/logo for website.png" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
      <div id="bubble1" class="bubbles">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/designer_drac/"><img src="assests/Instagram.png" alt="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/designer_drac/" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="bubble2" class="bubbles">
        <img src="assests/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" height="100px" width="100px">
      </div>
      <div id="bubble3" class="bubbles">
        <img src="assests/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" height="100px" width="100px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
  </DOCTYPE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some minor errors in your javascript, so I cleaned it up a bit. Here's the same code revised:

```js
function bubblefade() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("bubbles")[0] != undefined) {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("bubbles")].forEach(element => element.classList.replace("bubbles", "bubblefadestyle"));
  } else {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("bubblefadestyle")].forEach(element => element.classList.replace("bubblefadestyle", "bubbles"));
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

#logo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#logo:active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.05s;
}

.bubblefadestyle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bubbles {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bubbles:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.bubbles:active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.05s;
}

#bubble1 {
  padding-top: 130%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

<body>
  <div onclick="bubblefade();" id="logo">
    <img src="assests/logo for website.png" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="100px">
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="bubble1" class="bubbles">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/designer_drac/"><img src="assests/Instagram.png" alt="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/designer_drac/" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="bubble2" class="bubbles">
      <img src="assests/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="bubble3" class="bubbles">
      <img src="assests/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```